# How to make a generic EJB class

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have tow entities named : Address and Client.
I have an interface whitch looks like :

```
public interface IDAOEnitityFactory extends Serializable{
List<Address> findAllByClass();
}
```

The implementation looks like :

```
 @Stateless
@Local(IDAOEnitityFactory.class)
 public class DAOEnitityFactory implements IDAOEnitityFactory {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MY_PU")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<Address> findAllByClass() {     
    return this.getAuditReader().createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(Address.class, true, false)
            .setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
}
```

So i want to make a generic implementation where i pass just the Adress or Client and findAllByClass return on of them.
How can i do that?

I have a bean :

```
@EJB
private IDAOEnitityFactory dao;
for(Address st:dao.findAllByClass()){
                System.out.println(st.getID);               
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that i found a solution :

```
public interface IDAOEnitityFactory extends Serializable{
T List<T> findAllByClass(Class c);
 }
```

---

```
@Stateless
@Local(IDAOEnitityFactory.class)
public class DAOEnitityFactory implements IDAOEnitityFactory {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MY_PU")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
@Override
public List<T> findAllByClass(Class c) {     
return this.getAuditReader().createQuery()
        .forRevisionsOfEntity(c, true, false)
        .setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
 }
```

---

```
@EJB
private IDAOEnitityFactory dao;
for(Object st:dao.findAllByClass(Address.class)){
            System.out.println((Address)st)st.getID);               
        }
```

Perhaps there are other solutions. hen?